# update attribute of current_user devise in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working with devise in Rails3. I am facing one problem to update attribute of user. This is current user, and when I am trying to update user, its not updating. when I see in @user.errors, it says that password can't be blank. I have gone through the [devise docs for this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) and use upate_without_password(params[:user]) but not working for me. Just for to know that I am using Mongodb. I have also gone through the same questions posted in stackoverflow but not working for me. Let me share the code:

in user model: 
 There is validation of password like this :

```
validates :password,
    presence: true,
    confirmation: true,
    length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 16 }
```

in user controller:

```
protect_from_forgery except: :update
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_without_password(params[:user])          
      sign_in(current_user, :bypass=>true)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :json => current_user.to_json(:only =>  [ :status])}
      end
    else         
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :json => @user.errors.to_json}
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the parameters I am sending in request

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"status"=>"verified", "_id"=>"user1"}, "id"=>"user1"}
```

I have also tried in Rails console. its showing false when I update_attributes but when I inspect the user object its shows me updated.

```
1.9.3p286 :008 > user.update_attributes({"status"=>"verified"})
 => false
```

Any suggestion what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your User model whether you have specified this:

```
validates :password,:presence=>true
```

change the above validation to be done only on creating a user like this:

```
validates :password,:presence=>true,:on=>:create
```

This will skip the password validation while updating

Comment: Add :on=>:create to the validation so that this will not be validated while updating

Comment: Thank you, its working now with the solution you have provided.